# How to support multiple language in a application?

Tags: android

we will know that how to use multiple language in a single application . We are using four language to show our contents such as English, Russian, German, French. Follow below steps.

Step 1- Prepare string resource for the four language like English,French,Russian and German.
Step2- Created string.xml file for all four language
Read more at Findnerd.

Comment: Your steps is correct. What problem you facing?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages.html